# Difference between raise or lift one's head

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

[image]

Is the guy in the picture raising or lifting his head?

An [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turned%20up%20his%20head%2Craised%20his%20head%2Clifted%20his%20head&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cturned%20up%20his%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craised%20his%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clifted%20his%20head%3B%2Cc0) gave me more or less the same number of results, but I'm not sure I can rely on that since some sentences refer to other contexts, such as raising one's head from the bed, which is not what the guy in the picture is doing.

I was thinking of 'turn one's head up', but I got almost zero results, which is strange. Technically speaking the guy is turning his head. To raise or lift one's head should look more like an upward movement, like when one cranes their neck, without changing the angle, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is looking upwards, or turning his *face* upwards.

We can speak of both *raising* and *lifting* the head, but they usually imply that the head was in a low position to start with. Maybe the person was reading, or nodding because they felt tired, and when someone called their name they straightened their neck and began to look around.